# How do you find the original protocol (or port) of requests where Kubernetes is terminating SSL?

Tags: ssl, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-ingress

I am wanting to achieve the follow redirections and ensure that they all happen in one step:

- http://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- https://example.com -> https://www.example.com
- http://www.example.com -> https://www.example.com

I have a Kubernetes (1.15.5) cluster on Digital Ocean using `stable/nginx-ingress` (installed via helm) and also using `cert-manager` to handle SSLs.

In my Ingress config I have disabled ssl redirection as I want to handle this in the services themselves:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: proxy
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    certmanager.k8s.io/acme-challenge-type: http01
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - example.com
    - www.example.com
    secretName: tls-example-com
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-service
          servicePort: 80
  - host: www.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: nginx-service
          servicePort: 80
```

One of my services is a nginx server:

```
server {
    server_name  example.com;
    return 301 https://wwww.$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name  www.example.com;

    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    # app
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

However, `$scheme` here, is always '"http"', which makes sense as my service only receives requests on port 80. But just as the original address (host information) is forwarded to my service, how can I find out what the original port was?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nginx set up by the ingress controller acts as a reverse proxy and inserts X-Forwarded-* headers for the services behind it to read. Your service has to use those to get the correct client ip, port or scheme.

For nginx you can use `$http_x_forwarded_proto`:

```
  if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works perfectly. It also explains why I struggled to find reference to these variables, they're [dynamic based on the request](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_), and the docs refers to the variable as [`$http_`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html).